# Angular2 dynamic pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I'm using a pipe to internationalize my app:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {I18nService} from './i18n.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'i18n'
})
export class I18nPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private i18nService: I18nService) {
  }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.i18nService.get(value);
  }

}
```

This pipe calls a service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

const i18n = {
  en: {
    hello: 'Hello'
  },
  fr: {
    hello: 'Salut'
  }
};

@Injectable()
export class I18nService {

  language: string = 'en';

  constructor() {
  }

  get(key: string) {
    let languageObject = i18n[this.language];
    return languageObject[key];
  }

}
```

In a component I use it like this:

```
<div (click)="switchLanguage()">{{'hello' | i18n}}</div>

switchLanguage() {
  this.i18nService.language = 'en' ? 'en' : 'fr';
}
```

However, even though the service language value has been changed, the pipe result is not reevaluated. I need to navigate to any other route and come back to see this change taken into account.

I tried ApplicationRef.tick() and NgZone.run(callback) without any luck.

Any idea on how to reevaluate every pipes of the app, without navigating to another route or reloading the page ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use faked parameter to trigger pipe manually https://plnkr.co/edit/GsSJCRge8ulBzaRFokzj?p=preview Or you have to change your input string https://plnkr.co/edit/v6bfN8ri8lYuAhWrb3TZ?p=preview

Comment: Right, but that'd mean adding this fake param everywhere I internationalize something

Answer (score 2):

Your pipe should be marked as not pure, because the result of its transformation for a given input can change even though the input hasn't changed.

See [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#pure-and-impure-pipes) for explanations.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'i18n',
  pure: false
})
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot ! (note to myself, read the FULL documentation next time...)

Comment: But it seems that, performance wise, this is not a good choice, specially for an i18n pipe which will be used everywhere. Any chance I could trigger the reevaluation of a 'pure' pipe manually ?

Comment: I don't think so. A directive is probably a better idea than a pipe for this. AngularJS 1.x filters had the same performance problems, and the $translate project recommends using its directive rather than its pipe. That said, if your implementation really looks like it is in your question, and doesn't have to interpolate or anything, getting the translation will be very fast, and probably fast enough.

Comment: Both having an impure pipe reevaluated at each change or a cumbersome directive look expensive just in order to avoid a page reload. Language changes won't occur very often, I'm sad to say that I think I'll go for a page reload.

Comment: This is surprising that there's no way to recreate the components tree manually with the "new version" of the pure pipe