# Angular2: How to modify content of the element with custom directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

Angular2:

I'm trying to modify the content / `innerHTML` of the tag which has the custom directive applied.

**Preface:**

I'm trying to work out a translation functionality for my project which pulls data from DB, loads it into local object and update all translated object values. First I tried with a pipe, but unless the pipe is impure (which comes with performance degradation) - I have no way of updating the value when new translations arrive (Something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565167/angular2-dynamic-pipe)). Next in line is the directive, although it has larger footprint in the code.

**What I tried:**

I have a directive like that:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[i18n]'
})
export class I18nDirective
{
    @Input() set i18n(key: string) {
        this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = Translations.get(key);
        this.viewContainer.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = Translations.get(key);
        this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = Translations.get(key);
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', Translations.get(key));
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.viewContainer.element.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', Translations.get(key));
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', Translations.get(key));

        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }

    public constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private renderer: Renderer,
    ) { }
}
```

I've tried all the above variants of settings the contents of the tag under the directive, but without any success.

Here is the tag:

```
<span class="..." *i18n="'translation-page-title'"></span>
```

How can I change dynamically the innerHTML of the tag containing the directive? And probably change it dynamically when the language is changed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is probably not answer but there is ready functionality for translation which may be help you -> https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1

Comment: Yea, but I'm fetching the translations from the back-end API and I need dynamic updates. Pipes are more static/pure or impure, which have performance issues. If I have them beforehand like the article it won't be a problem - pipes won't have to be aware of any new data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the * before a directive it automatically wraps the content between the opening and the closing tags with `<template>...</template>`. Those tags are escaped from the browsers and this gives you the ability to modify the the content. Then you inject it using TemplateRef into the directive and do the modifications using `createEmbeddedView`. Since you don't need that you can just remove the * and use Renderer to modify the content. Here is a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/o5wxwCdcU8EJfd2zSXyH?p=preview) without Translations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Can you just edit the link to point to the example so others can see it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume that `Translations.get(key)` is asynchronous and is either a `Promise`, `Observable` or something that takes a callback. Is this correct? If so, you may need to wait for it to return the data:

```
Translations.get(key).then(function(data) {
  el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
});
```

Also try removing the asterisk in the HTML code:

```
<span i18n="'translation-page-title'"></span>
```

Comment: No it's not async. It reads from an object which is either populated with translations or not. Either way it returns translation if it's populated and key exists, or the key itself. Neither of them are showing right now.
Also when I remove the asterisk I get an error "No provider for TemplateRef". It should be there so the element can be converted to a `<template>`.

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to use a `<template>` for a simple translation in the form of `string`?

Comment: Without reference to `templateRef` I cannot call `viewContainer.createEmbeddedView`, which if not present - does not insert the `<span>` in the DOM at all.